# Editing admin pages in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I’m trying to find information on how to edit admin pages in **wordpress**, in my case this is the woocommerce order edit page.

Custom pages can be overridden in the site template, but I still do not understand how to deal with the admin.

If there are those who came across this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems better-suited for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: What you’re asking for probably isn’t possible. You can’t just edit the admin pages. Besides you’re talking about a non Wordpress owned product (WooCommerce) have you tried their documentation or support for what you’re trying to do? What have you done so far?